# How to deal with templates of completely different areas (but same website) with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

I have a webapp with a main index.html that shows each page through an ng-view and a routeProvider.

Now I'm adding an entry page for users who are still not logged in. This page could also have his own ng-view to slide different sections for non logged users (welcome, what is, sign in, sign up ecc...) and his own head with css scripts ecc...

I'd rather that both the webapp index and the entry page index address to www.example.com (so nothing like www.example.com/welcome ).

I thought about a structure similar to this:

> - webapp/
>
>   - main/
>   - page1/
>   - page2/
>   - welcome/
>
>     - section1/
>     - section2/
>     - index.html
>     - welcome.js (angular module for the entry page)
>   - .htaccess
>   - index.html
>   - webapp.js (angular module containing the routeProvider for the webapp)

Currently I have that .htaccess that rewrites all the fake queries to index.html so that everything is handled here.

So in particular:

1) How can I say to the routerProvider of webapp.js to go to /welcome/index.html when the user is not logged in, if I already use this condition for the webapp main page? (Should I use the run method? a brief example will be helpful)

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when(...)
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'main/webapp-main.html'
    })
    .when(...)
```

2) How do I prevent that everything in welcome/index.html will be loaded within the index.html ng-view? (maybe using ng-if to hide ng-view? or there is some way to control this behavour with the routerProvider?)

3) There is a better and simpler way to achieve all of this?

Thanks.

**Update:**
Ok I think there was an underlying problem in my question... I can't use a complete different page since everything is loaded in  and switching to another page will cause the reload of the app loosing all the data.
So I suppose I should use the same main template for the entire website.
Then I add: there is a way in angularjs to load different style sheets dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this questions is old but i think is valid and can clarify someone a few thinks.

First of all you are suppose to use a single page for AngularJS apps, otherwise you will have to do something like a redirect link, and in your other-index.html load an entirely different Angular Application also loading every script needed in the first one.

1) Use [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is easy to work, and very robust, the only thing you need to have is a container for your `ui-view` then the `ui-router` will fill the container with the corresponding html

2) To prevent navigation you should do something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function($rootScope, mySessionService){
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function(event, next, nextParams, prev, prevParams) {
        // The info of your currentUser could be obtain from a service
        // or localStorage or cookies anyway you are already doing it
        var authorized= checkAuthorization(next.authorazedRoles,             
                          mySessionService.getCurrentRol());
        if(!authorized) {
          $rootScope.$state.go('defaultState');
          // Or $rootScope.$emit('NOT_AUTHENTICATED');
          // and some service will have to implement a listener for this emit
          // $rootScope.$on('NOT_AUTHENTICATED', func..redirect to X State)
        }
      });
});
```